# What Am I - Short Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> Two bodies I have,
>   Though both joined in one
>   The stiller I stand - 
>   The faster I run

This is an old-classic riddle

*From The Book of Riddle
Portland: Bailey & Noyes.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you an:

> Hourglass?

Two bodies I have 
Though both joined into one:

> It has a top compartment and a bottom one and is connected.

The stiller I stand - The faster I run

> If it is still, the sand runs faster into the other compartment and if it is not still, it is harder for the sand to get into the other side. (kind of a stretch)

Comment: I had the same thought, but I think the last line just doesn't work. (Though I won't be surprised if this is the intended answer...)

Comment: Yeah.. This is a very common riddle (at least I think) and this is usually the intended answer.

Comment: "and the most part of me is the earth that you see" I just crafted that one... @Duck you're correct and Gareth you would've gone for it

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> the spacetime continuum?

Explanation:

> Space and time are two separate concepts that are both part of the same entity, spacetime. The slower you move through space, the faster you move through time (and vice versa), because of relativity.

Comment: Hm, it says "The stiller **I** stand - The faster **I** run", so I'm not 100% sure if this is correct.

Comment: This is a really nice concept but rather too advanced. Although it mentions a hint to the answer though